# How to return an input tensor after swapaxes numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

I wanted to split my tensor:

```
([[[[ -633.,   377.,  -691.,  -683.,    50.,   936.],
    [ -121.,   851.,  -593.,  -943.,   891.,   410.],
    [ -776.,  -560.,  -270.,   816.,   425.,  -629.],
    [ -172.,   599.,  -549.,  -520.,  -684.,   -57.],
    [  265.,  -323.,   726.,   -98.,   780.,   109.],
    [   22., -1017.,    22.,   248.,  -617.,   449.]]]])
```

in pooling blocks vector like below:

```
stride = 2
c = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2] // stride, stride, x.shape[3] // stride, stride).swapaxes(3, 4).reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], -1, stride * stride)

[[[[ -633.   377.  -121.   851.]
   [ -691.  -683.  -593.  -943.]
   [   50.   936.   891.   410.]
   [ -776.  -560.  -172.   599.]
   [ -270.   816.  -549.  -520.]
   [  425.  -629.  -684.   -57.]
   [  265.  -323.    22. -1017.]
   [  726.   -98.    22.   248.]
   [  780.   109.  -617.   449.]]]]
```

After that I wanted to get back my input tensor, but I can't understand how can I make it

Comment: Did you try to reshape (reverse the last reshape), then swap, and finally another reshape.  If you noted what each step produced - shape wise, you should be able to play it backwards.

Comment: So far, you did (1,1,6,6) -> (1,1,3,2,3,2) -> (1,1,3,3,2,2) -> (1,1,9,4), right?  Reverse (1,1,9,4) -> (1,1,3,3,2,2) -> (1,1,3,2,3,2)-> ...